# Easily create a colored countries map

Tags: image-editor, maps

I would like to quickly create a map showing the [AIIB member countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_Infrastructure_Investment_Bank#Member_countries), something like this map:

[image: Schengen countries]

Ideally, I would:

1. Open the tool
2. Click on the countries I want to be painted with a color
3. Ideally crop the map if only interested in a particular part of the world
4. Save the result

Requirements:

- Result file should be public domain, at least MUST be reusable in Wikipedia
- Result file MUST be SVG
- Faster than downloading an SVG and editing it.
- Ideally several color, but on/off (two colors) is OK too.

Webapp preferred but any platform is acceptable.

Comment: A good question (+1). I would also like this, especially if it can also colo(u)r code regions within a country (states, shires, etc). Of course, for bonus marks, it would be great if it can output HTML with JS to handle clicking on a country or region, but that is stretching the scope of your question (I may just ask my own).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you take a look at [python](http://python.org) + [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) + the [basemap toolkit](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/index.html?highlight=basemap) and/or [cartopy](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery.html) - as this SO Question shows you can select countries based on a number of criteria and colour them as you wish.

- Output to numerous file formats
- Selection on numerous criteria
- Results are your own - you can place in the public domain
- Multiple colours available
- You get to pick the center, crop and projection
- Free both price and FOSS
- Cross platform.
- You can either save your plot programmatically or, in the view window, you can save image in a number of formats.

### Example

From the answers to the question referenced above:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib as mp

from shapelib import ShapeFile
import dbflib
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib import cm

def get_shapeData(shp,dbf):
  for npoly in range(shp.info()[0]):
    shpsegs = []
    shpinfo = []

    shp_object = shp.read_object(npoly)
    verts = shp_object.vertices()
    rings = len(verts)
    for ring in range(rings):
        if ring == 0:
            shapedict = dbf.read_record(npoly)
        name = shapedict["name_long"]
        continent = shapedict["continent"]
        lons, lats = zip(*verts[ring])
        if max(lons) > 721. or min(lons) < -721. or max(lats) > 91. or min(lats) < -91:
            raise ValueError,msg
        x, y = m(lons, lats)
        shpsegs.append(zip(x,y))
        shapedict['RINGNUM'] = ring+1
        shapedict['SHAPENUM'] = npoly+1
        shpinfo.append(shapedict)

    lines = LineCollection(shpsegs,antialiaseds=(1,))
    lines.set_facecolors(cm.jet(np.random.rand(1)))
    lines.set_edgecolors('k')
    lines.set_linewidth(0.3)
    ax.add_collection(lines)


if __name__=='__main__':

  f=figure(figsize=(10,10))
  ax = plt.subplot(111)
  m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=30,urcrnrlat=72,\
            llcrnrlon=-40,urcrnrlon=50,resolution='c')
  m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.1,color='w')

  sfile = 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries'

  shp = ShapeFile(sfile)
  dbf = dbflib.open(sfile)
  get_shapeData(shp,dbf)

  show()
  sys.exit(0)
```

Which results in:
[image: Example Map]

You might also like to take a look at [plotly](https://plot.ly) which allows more online use but the last time that I looked hadn't fully implemented basemap.

Comment: Does the "number of formats" include SVG? Did you mean to link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16563397/226958 ?